# C# Compare two XML files and Replace Values

Tags: c#, xml, compare, edit

i have two XML files, i would like to read both with C# and transfer the values from the old XML file to the new XML file.

i have searched few hours but can not find a solution for my Problem, so i hope anyone from here can help me out.

```
//New File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hmi-resources>
  <resource id="Plasma0">
    <value>Plasma 0</value>
  </resource>
  <resource id="Plasma1">
    <value>Plasma 1</value>
  </resource>
  <resource id="Plasma2">
    <value>Plasma 2</value>
  </resource>
  <resource id="Plasma3">
    <value>Plasma 3</value>
  </resource>
</hmi-resources>


//Old File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hmi-resources>
  <resource id="Plasma0">
    <value>NEW Plasma 123</value>
  </resource>
  <resource id="Plasma1">
    <value>NEW Plasma abc</value>
  </resource>
</hmi-resources>
```

Comment: Have a look at deserializing / serializing xml to and from objects https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-deserialize-an-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xml Linq with a Join should work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string OLD_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string NEW_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument oldDoc = XDocument.Load(OLD_FILENAME);
            XDocument newDoc = XDocument.Load(NEW_FILENAME);

            var query = (from o in oldDoc.Descendants("resource")
                        join n in newDoc.Descendants("resource") on (string)o.Attribute("id") equals (string)n.Attribute("id")
                        select new { o = o, n = n })
                       .ToList();

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                item.n.Element("value").SetValue((string)item.o.Element("value"));
            }
        }
    }

}
```